# YAML configuration in spring-core

Tags: spring, spring-config

Is there a way to use YAML configuration without spring boot. From docs its clear it may not be possible but experts may have other opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way. You need  to use [`YamlPropertiesFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.html) which is capable of reading/parsing yaml files.

You need this dependency on the classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Next you can load the properties from the yaml file and inject them into a
`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` using the `getObject()` method of `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean` which returns an instance of `java.util.Properties`

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
  yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yml"));
  propertyConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
  return propertyConfigurer;
}
```

You can then inject the properties from the yaml file using `@Value` for exmple.